# How to calculate value in puppet erb file

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have the following value im my application my_app.pp value:

```
akka_application_cluster_seed_nodes => '"akka.tcp://ActorSystem@host1:2551","akka.tcp://ActorSystem@host2:2551","akka.tcp://ActorSystem@host3:2551"'
```

Now in my erb file `min-nr-of-members` value should be calculated by getting the size of `akka_application_cluster_seed_nodes` array divide by 2 plus 1

```
 $min-nr-of-members = $akka_application_cluster_seed_nodes.size/2 +1
```

For example:

```
  auto-down-unreachable-after = <%= get_param('akka_cluster_auto_down_unreachable_after')%>

and something like this:
      <% $cluster= get_param('akka_cluster_auto_down_unreachable_after') %>
      <% $minNumOfNodes = ($cluster.size / 2)+1 %>

min-nr-of-members = <% $minNumOfNodes %>
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<% minNumOfNodes = (@akka_application_cluster_seed_nodes.split(',').length / 2)+1 %>
min-nr-of-members = <%=minNumOfNodes%>
```

Inside the <% %> it is just straight Ruby, so we take the raw string, split it on the comma, take the count, then do the required calculation on that.